# "List index out of range" and "Can't convert list object to str implicitly" Errors

Tags: postgresql, python-3.x, psycopg2

When I try to run the code

```
hiscores = ""
    for i in range(1, 11):
        hiscores += interact_database("SELECT MAX(Correct), Name FROM Score GROUP BY Name, Correct ORDER BY Correct DESC LIMIT %s OFFSET 1", str(i,))[0][0]
        hiscores += " "
        hiscores += interact_database("SELECT MAX(Correct), Name FROM Score GROUP BY Name, Correct ORDER BY Correct DESC LIMIT %s OFFSET 1;", str(i,))[0][0]
        hiscores += "\n"
```

I get the error

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

But when I remove the parentheses I get another error,

```
TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly
```

Does anyone know how to fix this error? I've done the same in other places, but there I used a `return` instead. However, I'm afraid that my code will become a tasty plate of spaghetti when I add too much functions.

Comment: Seems you don't have that many items in the database. It's not about the database query, it's about trying to access an empty list in Python. Also it's a bad practice to send multiple queries to the database when you could do it with one. Also using OFFSET 1 but changing the LIMIT is quite pointless since you always get the same result.

Comment: I added some values to the database and it worked, thanks! Also, you're right about LIMIT and OFFSET, I should edit OFFSET each time.

Comment: What you should do is to make a single query for all the values you want and then read them, not make 20 queries. It really is bad to do it this way and if you don't learn how to do it properly from the start it'll get worse in the future.

Comment: Do you mean by using subqueries?

Comment: No, you run the query with `LIMIT 10` and you automatically get 10 rows. You don't need to ask for a single row each time and especially you don't need to ask for the data again just to get a different column from it.

Comment: And then I can extract the values with [1][0], [2][0] etc... I see. Thanks a lot, this will certainly improve my code!